# Powershell doesn't open - error "Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace"

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm simply trying to open Powershell on my server. It opens for about 5 seconds and then closes, not showing any error before it closes or anything. The only thing I can see is in the Windows Powershell Event Log is that it gives the following error:

> "Settings: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace."

I'm running WMF 4, Server 2012 R2, Exchange Server 2016 (not that I think that has anything to do with it). Any other post I've seen when I google " Powershell Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace" always seems to have to do with someone programming. I'm just trying to open powershell.

Comment: Try and run Powershell via Cmd. That is, `win+r` -> `cmd` -> `powershell` to see if there's some error message on the console. Try using `-NoProfile` parameter too in case there's something amiss on one of the profile files.

Comment: Tried it with the noprofile parameter and it still closed out with no error information. Just another event the event log.

Comment: The _cmd shell window_ closes too?

Comment: How are you trying to open PowerShell?  From the Start Menu?  By double-clicking an existing `.ps1` file?

Comment: CMD shell does not close. @BaconBits Through shortcut on desktop. I've also gone to the actual location of the file and it does the same

Comment: Since this is an Exchange server, can you open [Exchange Management Shell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638134(v=exchg.160).aspx)?

Comment: I cannot. That's how I discovered it, lol

Comment: What happened when you tried to run Powershell via Cmd?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it went into powershell for 5 seconds or so and then went back into cmd prompt mode, as indicated by the title bar of the cmd prompt window and the prompt no longer having "PS" at the beginning.

Comment: Nothing in any of the standard profiles: `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`, `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`, `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`?  Has WinRM already been configured on the system?  If so, can you connect with a remote session?  Have you tried a different user?  Were .Net updates applied requiring a reboot?

Comment: So, checked all those other things except for another user trying it. When I found someone to try it, they knew about a change they made in group policy, which was "Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Components\Windows Powershell\Turn on Powershell Transcripting" had been set to enabled. Once we turned that off, normal Powershell opens. However, the Exchange management shell still won't open with the same error in the OP.

Comment: Okay, after changing the group policy back, doing a gpupdate, then rebooting the server, it finally works properly. Whoever poses that as the answer (make sure to include the GPO setting that needed to be changed) will get their post marked as the answer.

Comment: @Joseph You've got more than 15 reputation.  You can (and should) answer the question yourself and then (in 48 hours) accept the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a group policy setting, specifically "Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Components\Windows Powershell\Turn on Powershell Transcripting." It had been turned on in our domain because Powershell V5 is being/has been pushed out to everyone (except for our Exchange Servers). Once I changed the setting on a GPO closer to my Exchange Servers, did a gpupdate, then restarted the server, it started working again just fine.

Also, whoever downvoted my question, would you be so kind to explain why it was downvoted? Or are you just going to be a drive by downvoter?